# How to replace variables in the header and in tables with docx4j?

Tags: java, docx4j

I'm trying to replace variables in the header of a document and in tables but I don't know how to proceed. I managed to replace variables in the body of the document but this method (using ${}) does not work for the headers and tables.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.docx4j.XmlUtils;
import org.docx4j.customxml.ObjectFactory;
import org.docx4j.dml.wordprocessingDrawing.Inline;
import org.docx4j.jaxb.Context;
import org.docx4j.model.datastorage.migration.VariablePrepare;
import org.docx4j.model.structure.HeaderFooterPolicy;
import org.docx4j.model.structure.SectionWrapper;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.exceptions.Docx4JException;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.CustomXmlDataStoragePart;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.Part;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.PartName;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.Parts;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.WordprocessingML.BinaryPartAbstractImage;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.WordprocessingML.HeaderPart;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.WordprocessingML.MainDocumentPart;
import org.docx4j.utils.BufferUtil;
import org.docx4j.wml.Hdr;
import org.docx4j.wml.HdrFtrRef;
import org.docx4j.wml.HeaderReference;

import java.util.Locale;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.WordprocessingML.HeaderPart;
import org.docx4j.wml.HdrFtrRef;

public class EditInvoice {

    private static WordprocessingMLPackage  template;
    private static ObjectFactory factory;

    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {  

        boolean save = true;
        String outputfilepath = System.getProperty("user.dir")+ "/InvoiceEdited.docx";

        java.util.Date uDate = new java.util.Date();
        java.sql.Date sDate = new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
        sDate = new java.sql.Date(uDate.getTime());
        uDate = new java.util.Date(sDate.getTime());
        Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
        DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL, locale);

        //System.out.println(dateFormat.format(sDate));


        template = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(new FileInputStream(new File("invoice_template_sample.docx")));
        VariablePrepare.prepare(template);

        List<SectionWrapper> sectionWrappers = template.getDocumentModel().getSections();

        MainDocumentPart documentPart = template.getMainDocumentPart();

        HashMap<String, String> variables = new HashMap<String, String>();

        // populate doc variables
        variables.put("Name", "John Doe");
        variables.put("Phone", "(123) 456 78 90");
        variables.put("CompanyName", "BSI Business Systems Integration AG");
        variables.put("Email", "john.doe@bsiag.com");
        variables.put("CompanyAddress", "Täfernstrasse 16a, 5405 Baden");
        variables.put("InvoiceNo", "No. 2013-007");
        variables.put("InvoiceDate", dateFormat.format(sDate));
        variables.put("BillingName", "Jane Smith");
        variables.put("PayableToName", "John Doe, BSI");
        variables.put("SubTotal", "$1,530.00");
        variables.put("SalesTax", "$229.50");
        variables.put("Shipping", "$250.00");
        variables.put("Total", "$2,009.50");

        // and content for embedded table
        Object[][] orderItems = new Object[][]{
            new Object[]{"1", "Table", "$800.00", "$800.00"},
            new Object[]{"4", "Chair", "$150.00", "$600.00"},
            new Object[]{"1", "Assembling", "$130.00", "$130.00"},
        };


        try
        {

            documentPart.variableReplace(variables);
            //documentPart.addObject(orderItems);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }


        if (save) {
            template.save(new java.io.File(outputfilepath) );
        } else {
            System.out.println(XmlUtils.marshaltoString(documentPart.getContents(), true, true));
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Post your code?  There's no reason why it shouldn't work in headers and tables.

Comment: `docx` is a zip with contents.xml. Using a `jar:file://...` URL one can use a zip file system in java to simple replace the content.xml with a new one.

Answer (score 0):

To replace variables in headers, you need to do variable replacement to the relevant header parts.  Here, you're only doing it in the main document part.

Regarding tables, the variable replacement stuff isn't designed to duplicate rows (eg one row per invoice line item).  In other words, it won't insert rows.  So without more code on your part, your Object[][] orderItems won't do anything.

(In contrast, docx4j's XML data binding does handle that, using an OpenDoPE od:repeat)